# Swift 4 tableview not showing data using generic completion handler

Tags: ios, swift, completionhandler

I'm having issue with completion handler using generic function, it seems that it won't pass anything on the `UITableView`, unless I will put some break point on it, please check my code below:

```
public func requestGenericData<T: Decodable>(urlString: String, httpMethod: String?, token: String!, completion: @escaping(T) ->()) {
    let fullStringUrl = url + urlString
    guard let url = URL(string: fullStringUrl) else { return }
    guard let token = token else { return }
    var urlRequest = URLRequest(url: url)
    urlRequest.setValue("application/json", forHTTPHeaderField: "accept")
    urlRequest.setValue("Bearer \(token)", forHTTPHeaderField: "Authorization")
    urlRequest.httpMethod = httpMethod
    URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: urlRequest) { (data, response, error) in
        if self.isInternetAvailable() {
            guard let data = data else { return }
            if let httpResponse = response as? HTTPURLResponse {
                if httpResponse.statusCode >= 200 && httpResponse.statusCode < 300 {
                    do {
                        let obj = try JSONDecoder().decode(T.self, from: data)
                        completion(obj)
                    } catch {
                        print("Error: \(String(describing: error))\n StatusCode: \(httpResponse.statusCode)")
                    }
                }
            }
        } else {
            showAlert(title: "No Internet Connect", message: "Please open your network and try again.", alertStyle: .alert, buttonTitle: "OK", buttonStyle: .default)
            return
        }
    }.resume()
}
```

and this is the function that will show the list of of it's result in the table view code below:

```
func listOfServicesMenus() {
    var jobsInCategory = [String]()
    apiHelper.requestGenericData(urlString: "nothing/more/than/a/noob", httpMethod: "GET", token: token) { (noobs: Noobs) in
        for job in jobs.jobCategories {
            jobsInCategory.append(job.name)
            for jobDetails in job.getJobs {
                jobsInCategory.append(jobDetails.name)
            }
        }
        self.listOfServices.dropView.dropDownOptions = jobsInCategory
    }
}
```

New to swift and developing iOS, it seems that when ever I put break point on it seems working fine, how ever when not, it doesn't show anything?

Does anyone any idea on how to implement a proper completion handler with generics or do I missed something on it when try to write this code?

Thanks for those who are helping me out of this.

**Update**
I created a so called `DropDownMenu` using `UIView`, `UITableViewDelegate`, `UITableViewDataSource`, `UITableView` (which is created under the `UIView` for proper handling of constraints).

**Update 2**

Added implementation of `UITableView`(under `UIView`)

```
class dropDownView: UIView, UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource {

var dropDownOptions = [String]()
var tableView = UITableView()
var delegate: DropDownDelegate!

override init(frame: CGRect) {
    super.init(frame: frame)
    self.layer.backgroundColor = UIColor.clear.cgColor
    self.backgroundColor = UIColor.clear
    tableView.delegate = self
    tableView.dataSource = self

    tableView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    tableView.layer.cornerRadius = 10
    tableView.backgroundColor = UIColor(displayP3Red: 166/255, green: 203/255, blue: 69/255, alpha: 1.0)
    self.addSubview(tableView)

    tableView.leftAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.leftAnchor).isActive = true
    tableView.rightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.rightAnchor).isActive = true
    tableView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.topAnchor).isActive = true
    tableView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.bottomAnchor).isActive = true

}

required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
    fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
}

func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
    return 1
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    let cell = UITableViewCell()
    cell.contentView.backgroundColor = UIColor.clear
    return dropDownOptions.count
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = UITableViewCell()
    cell.textLabel?.text = dropDownOptions[indexPath.row]
    cell.textLabel?.textColor = UIColor(displayP3Red: 166/255, green: 203/255, blue: 69/255, alpha: 1.0)
    cell.layer.borderColor = UIColor(displayP3Red: 112/255, green: 112/255, blue: 112/255, alpha: 1.0).cgColor
    cell.backgroundColor = UIColor(displayP3Red: 254/255, green: 252/255, blue: 215/255, alpha: 1.0)
    cell.selectionStyle = .none
    cell.textLabel?.textAlignment = .center
    return cell
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    let selectedCell: UITableViewCell = tableView.cellForRow(at: indexPath)!
    selectedCell.contentView.backgroundColor = UIColor(displayP3Red: 133/255, green: 178/255, blue: 56/255, alpha: 1.0)
    selectedCell.textLabel?.textColor = UIColor.white
    self.delegate.dropDownPressed(string: self.dropDownOptions[indexPath.row])
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didDeselectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    let cellToDeSelect:UITableViewCell = tableView.cellForRow(at: (indexPath))!
    cellToDeSelect.contentView.layer.borderColor = UIColor(displayP3Red: 112/255, green: 112/255, blue: 112/255, alpha: 1.0).cgColor
    cellToDeSelect.contentView.backgroundColor = UIColor(displayP3Red: 254/255, green: 252/255, blue: 215/255, alpha: 1.0)
    cellToDeSelect.textLabel?.textColor = UIColor(displayP3Red: 166/255, green: 203/255, blue: 69/255, alpha: 1.0)
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, willDisplay cell: UITableViewCell, forRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    cell.contentView.backgroundColor = UIColor.clear
}
```

Comment: try reloading tableView after setting `     self.listOfServices.dropView.dropDownOptions = jobsInCategory`

Comment: Probably not related but checking `isInternetAvailable` after `dataTask` has returned something is nonsensical.

Comment: @AnilVarghese can't access the reloadData(). would you mind check my code for the implemetation of `UITableView`.

Comment: PS: And creating a new cell in `numberOfRowsInSection`  has no effect at all and is nonsensical, too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to you **Anil Varghese**, created another function that will reload data under the `dropDownView` class and added this line of code:

```
func reloadData() {
    DispatchQueue.main.async {
        self.tableView.reloadData()
    }
}
```